# div increases height, and moves a div next to it in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap right now and i'm having an issue.

This is my code:

```
<div id="calendario" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">...</div>
<div id="seccion" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-6">...</div>
<div id="fotos" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">...</div>
<div id="secciondos" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">...</div>
```

My layouts look like this:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/j387p9xvl/]

But when my calendar height is bigger, this is what happens:

[image: http://postimg.org/image/am8pect6p/]

What can I do to fix it?.

Comment: You don't seem to be using rows. Do.

Comment: Please clarify what exactly you're trying to fix. Obviously there's some confusion.

Comment: Sorry, when my calendar needs five rows, the layout is perfect, but when it needs six, seems like my layout in the second row, with the title "Homenaje al ciclista ..." is doing again col-lg-push-3

Comment: Please clarify your question *in your question*.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed it! :)

```
<div id="calendario" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    CALENDAR
</div>

<div id="seccion" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-6">
    SECTION 1
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-sm-block"></div>
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
<div id="fotos" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
    PICTURES
</div>
<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>
<div id="secciondos" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">
    SECTION 2
</div>
```

Just putting **clearfix class** where before the layout that is moved worked!

Thanks for the answers!!.

I can't vote up your comments because I don't have enough reputation :(.

Answer (score 0):

Using containers and rows as the Bootstrap team intended, it's easy to keep things aligned:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div id="calendario" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Calendar
            <br>Calendar</div>
        <div id="seccion" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-6">Section One</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div id="fotos" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">Section Two</div>
        <div id="secciondos" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-6 col-lg-push-3">Section Three</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://liveweave.com/lRGNdr)**

Comment: I'm not sure, I think in his example, he really want the calendar to the left and all the text to the right... Row would make The bottom right text far from the top right div when the calendar gets bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a wrapper around your calendar and make it `.col-md-6` and then another around your second section and add the `.col-md-6` class also. Like this, you would make sure that both your section will always talke half the screen. (You can also use other classes sm, xs and etc depeding on the layout you want to have)

For example:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div id="calendario" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-3">...</div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-6">
   <div id="seccion" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-9 col-lg-6">...</div>
 </div>
```

This way, you'd have to review also for example your seccion and calendar, because now the whol col-md-6 will contains 12 columns also. Hope it helped. You might want to review the Grid system in there also:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid